# Remove metadata from non-picture file using PHP

Tags: php, file, file-upload, upload, metadata

I've recently learned about Imagick and removing image exif/metadata.

However for my work, I was wondering if there was an alternative for the following file types:

Audio/mp3/wav/ogg/flac
text/txt/rtf
pdf
application/word/power point/excel

Imagick works as intended for stripping the file's metadata. I'm just unsure/can't find much info on removing metadata for other file tpyes!

Users will chose a file to upload, and whether its metadata is removed at all.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Different filetypes will require different tools.

For the audio formats, the metadata is embedded in a container. I think `ffmpeg` will be able to strip most of it .

And then for the pdf and Microsoft formats: these can be a bit more challenging. `exiftool` should be able to help you out in most cases.

I don't think txt, text and rtf can contain metadata. What are you aiming for with these?

Comment: Exiftool's edits to PDFs are reversible unless the file is re-linearise with a tool such as qpdf.  It cannot edit metadata in word/excel spreadsheets and such.  I'd agree with you on text files.

Comment: I've heard of exiftools and ffmpeg - however this is software is it not? Could I possibly import a library of sorts to use on my webserver?